# powershell export variable to txt file

Tags: string, powershell, variables, parameters, output

I need to extract a variable on a single line in a txt file like so;

```
Write-Host "Select RDS Collection to migrate"
$AllCollections.Keys | Sort-Object | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose "[$_] - $($AllCollections.$_)" -Verbose }
Write-Output ''
$Collection = $AllCollections.$((Read-Host -Prompt 'Choose collection number') -as [int])

$oldrdscb = "RDSCB01N01"
$newrdscb = "RDSCB02N01"
$newrdscbsmb = "\\$newrdscb\C$\temp\migrationvariables.txt"

echo "$collection" = "$Collection" | Out-File -FilePath $newrdscbsmb -append -width 200
```

txt file \RDSCB02N01\c$\temp\migrationvariables.txt now containts:

```
RDS-FSLOGIXTEST
=
RDS-FSLOGIXTEST
```

this because it reads the first $collection and the gives the output of $collection variable, which makes sense.
How can i get the result without the variable of the first $collection and send it as text instead of a variable so the end result in the txt would be:

```
$collection = TEST
```

The txt is emtpy before running this code.
The Goal here is to read the variables on my new rds server to migrate theme.

Any tips? thank you!

Comment: I dont understand the question...

Comment: Use the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) and a non expanding string in single quotes `'$collectionname = "{0}"' -f $Collection | Out-File -FilePath $newrdscbsmb -append -width 200`

Comment: where is `$collectioname` coming from? where is `$Collection` coming from? where is `$collections` coming from? what is in `"\\$newrdscb\C$\temp\migrationvariables.txt"` before you add to it? ///// **_please add the info needed to understand your code._**

Comment: @lotpings exactly what i need, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to escape the dollar signs using the backtick (`). It is usually above the tab key on the keyboard.

```
$oldrdscb = "RDSCB01N01"
$newrdscb = "RDSCB02N01"
$newrdscbsmb = "\\$newrdscb\C$\temp\migrationvariables.txt"

echo "`$collectioname" = "`$Collection" | Out-File -FilePath $newrdscbsmb -append -width 200
```